# Data from Extension to Webpage for Initial Load of the webpage - Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, messaging, firefox-addon-webextensions

Creating an extension for `Chrome` and `Firefox`. Based on our requirement, we need some of the information(previously stored in storage by extension) from extension to webpage at the time page load. Data  needed in webpage before any `XHR` request trigger from webpage. This is achieved in `Chrome` by following code **but unable to get the same for `Firefox`. Data not received to webpage as similar to Chrome as fast.**

**Note:** Webpage is a react application

**For Chrome (Working Code)**

```js
// Code in Webpage
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('extensionId', { messageFromWeb: 'Sample message' }, (response) =>{
    console.log('OnInit Page Details', response);
});

// Code in background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(async function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse({ detail: {} });
});
```

**For Firefox,** implemented the same with `window.postmessage` but it is not as fast as chrome, got data in delayed(after xhr request triggered from webpage, need to get before that).

```js
// Code in Webpage
window.postMessage({ type: 'FROM_WEB_PAGE' }, '*');

window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type === 'DATA_BACK_FROM_EXTENSION')) {
        console.log('On Init', event.data);
    }
}, false);


// Code in Content-Script
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type === "FROM_WEB_PAGE")) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage('GetInitialData');
    }
}, false);


// Code in background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (response) {
    window.postMessage( { type: 'DATA_BACK_FROM_EXTENSION', detail: response }, '*');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox there's an even faster method: [register a dynamically generated code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contentScripts/register) as a content script that runs at `document_start` and then [exposes the data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts) to the web page via `wrappedJSObject` so the page has direct access to the data synchronously, right at the start.

background script:

```js
let dataReg;
async function exposeData(data) {
  dataReg = await browser.contentScripts.register({
    js: [{
      code: `wrappedJSObject.__extensionData =
        cloneInto(${JSON.stringify(data)}, wrappedJSObject)`,
    }],
    matches: ['https://your.web.app/*'],
    runAt: 'document_start',
  });
}
```

Your web app then uses `window.__extensionData` directly.

Comment: Thanks Its working.. Is there any way to achieve the same in Safari as well? If possible, can u pls update the answer, so that it will be helpful for others as well